# AS3 - Convert String to Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I'm trying to store my images on a server to lighten the load of my SWF file.  I've spent all day trying to get the data from the server, but all I get is a seemingly random string (which I understand is the string value of my image).  I've tried reading up on this, but I haven't found anything that actually works, I get a lot of references to Base 64 encoding/decoding and I've tried a couple of libraries but they do nothing.  Here's what I have (I've simplified it a bit to upload it):

```
public function loadImage() : void {
    var url:String='example.com/some_image';
    var load:URLLoader=new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));
    load.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
}

public function onLoadComplete(event : Event) : void {
    var imgString:String=event.target.data;
}
```

But how do I convert imgString to a Bitmap or Sprite so I can addChild() it?  I've tried `imgString as Bitmap` which returns null.  Maybe it has something to do with the BitmapData class?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701892/load-image-bytecode-as-string-and-convert-it-into-bitmap-is-it-possible) seems similar but is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server that runs PHP, you can generate the image first, e.g.

```
// PHP script 'http://yoursite.com/image.php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $myImageDataFromDB; // Get the image data from MySQL.
```

And then in ActionScript, use the standard process to load that as an image:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yoursite.com/image.php");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);
```

Comment: I've tried using that method also, but it's giving me a bizarre error:

Exception fault: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.blah.moreblah.moreblah::SomeCompletelyUnrelatedClass()[...SomeCompletelyUnrelatedClass.as:37]

It won't give me the error if I don't put a new Loader(); but then it won't load the image.  You method should work though, so I'm marking it as accepted.

Comment: Your script works perfectly fine on a fresh project, so it's got to be a problem with my code somewhere else.

Comment: I finally got it to work, it was something completely unrelated causing the problem though.  Thank you for your help!